# Unable to login admin panel after installing better blog extension

Tags: extensions

I've downloaded the better blog extension and am also getting module details when i put the following command in command prompt

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

But when I have tried to login my `admin` panel, I'm getting an error and it says:

```
"Specified invalid parent id (Mageplaza_Core::menu)","1":"#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\magento2\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\Interception\\Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Backend\\Model\\Menu\\Builder->getResult(Object(Magento\\Backend\\Model\\Menu))\n#1 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\magento2\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\Interception\\Interceptor.php(138)
```

Comment: Clear your requirement , what exactly you need

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Mageplaza_Core module.

install This module, and run again

https://github.com/mageplaza/module-core